# PHP widget use class selector instead of <tag> to build menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I hope on of you clever chaps might be able to answer this riddle.

I have an excellent widget I am trying to integrate into my site. It creates menus from `<H1>, <H2>` etc, tags in the document. This is very useful as I can create sub menu navigation for each of my pages by styling the titles.

I am however using a wordpress theme that has extensions added to the editor that style various parts of the pages, including for example titles.

So the output from how it styles the title in HTML output is as follows for example:

```
<h1 class="grve-element grve-align-left grve-title-striped" style="">Visit</h1>
```

The PHP script I will load in below, the relevant section it appears to grab tags is:

```
    $tags_to_parse = "<h1>";
```

Is there a way I can tell this PHP script to grab this particular H1 class?

Cheers,

Tomek

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Anchors Menu
Description: Check Wordpress static pages content and create a widget menu with links that point to words between the HTML tags you chose.
Author: Gonçalo Rodrigues 
Version: 1.2
Author URI: http://www.goncalorodrigues.com
*/

/* Copyright 2010  Gonçalo Rodrigues  (email : gonafr [AT] gmail [DOT] com)

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/
//ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);

$count = -1;

add_action("init", "anc_insert_init");
add_filter("the_content", "anc_add_link_text");


// renders the list in your theme;
function anc_insert() 
{    
    $tags_to_parse = "<h1>";

    $current_page_id = get_the_ID();
    $page_data = get_page($current_page_id);
    $current_page_name = $page_data->post_name;

    $current_page_cat_id = get_cat_ID($current_page_name);

    $page_id = get_the_ID();

    // if it's blog style page
    if (is_home()){
        $count = 0;
        $content = "";
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $id_post = get_the_ID();
            $post = get_post($id_post);

            $content .= "<a name=\"$count\"></a>";
            $content .= $post->post_content;

            $count++;
        endwhile; else:
            //_e("Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.");
        endif;

        anc_list_menu($content);
        //echo "Sorry but this plugin only work on Wordpress pages.";
    }

    //if it's page style page
    else if(is_page()){
        $page_id = get_the_ID();
        $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
        //$title = $page_data->post_title; // Get title
        $content = $page_data->post_content;
        //if content is empty i will fetch all pages that are child of the current page and get their titles

        $fetch_children_pages = true;
        if (fetch_children_pages == true && $content==""){
            $content = "";
            $pages = get_pages('child_of='.$page_id.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');

            foreach($pages as $page)
            {       
                $content .= "<".$tags_to_parse.">".$page->post_title."</".$tags_to_parse.">";
                if(!$content)
                    continue;
                $count++;
            }
        }   
        anc_list_menu($content);
    }

    // if it's single post
    else if (is_single()){

        $content = "";
        $content .= get_the_content();
        anc_list_menu($content);
        //echo "Sorry but this plugin only work on Wordpress pages.";
    }

    //if it's a category page
    else if(is_category){

        //echo $current_page_cat_id;
        //echo $current_page_name;
        //echo $current_page_id;

        $current_cat = get_the_category();
        //echo 'teste'.$current_cat[0]->cat_name;

        $current_cat_id = get_cat_ID($current_cat[0]->cat_name);
        $posts = get_posts('$category_name='.$current_cat[0]->cat_name);
        $content = "";

        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            $id_post = get_the_ID();
            $post = get_post($id_post);
            $content .= "<".$tags_to_parse.">".$post->post_title."</".$tags_to_parse.">";

        endwhile; else:
            //_e("Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.");

        endif;
        anc_list_menu($content);    
        //echo "Sorry but this plugin only work on Wordpress pages.";
    }

    else {
        //_e("Error: This page is not a tradicional Wordpress Page or a Wordpress Blog!");
    }
}

// prints the menu with the links to the titles
function anc_list_menu($content){
    // list all tags
    $foo_tags = anc_get_tags($content); 

    if($foo_tags[1] != 0){
        $foo = -1;
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach($foo_tags[0] as $key => $val){
            $foo++;
            echo "<li><a href=\"#$foo\">".$val."</a></li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    }else{
        //no tags found
        //_e("Not found any tag of the type that was selected to be parsed.");
    }
}

// retrieve all words between tags
function anc_get_tags($content){
    global $tags_to_parse;

    $options = get_option("anc_tags");
    $tags_to_parse = $options["anc_tags"];

    $pattern_search = "/(<".$tags_to_parse.".*>)(.*)(<\/".$tags_to_parse.">)/isxmU";
    preg_match_all($pattern_search, $content, $patterns);
    $res = array();
    array_push($res, $patterns[2]);
    array_push($res, count($patterns[2]));

    return $res;
}

// insert widget
function anc_insert_init()
{
    //register the widget
    register_sidebar_widget("Anchors Menu", "anc_widget_insert");
    //register the widget control
    register_widget_control("Anchors Menu", "anc_widget_insert_control");   
}

function anc_widget_insert($args) {
    global $title, $tags_to_parse;

    extract($args);

    //get our options
    $options = get_option("anc_title");
    $title = $options["anc_title"];

    $options = get_option("anc_tags");
    $tags_to_parse = $options["anc_tags"];

    echo $before_widget;
    /*Insert any headers you want in the next line, between "?>" and "<?". Leave blank for no header. */
    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
    anc_insert();

    echo $after_widget;
}

// responsable for options in backoffice
function anc_widget_insert_control() {
    global $title, $tags_to_parse;

    //get saved options if user change things
    //handle user input
    if (isset($_POST["anc_insert_submit"])){
        $foo_title = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST["anc_title"]));
        $foo_tags = strtolower(stripslashes($_POST["anc_tags"]));

        $options["anc_title"] = $foo_title;
        $options["anc_tags"] = $foo_tags;

        update_option("anc_title", $options);
        update_option("anc_tags", $options);
    }
    else {
        //default options
        $options["anc_title"] = "Menu";
        $options["anc_tags"] = "h2";

        update_option("anc_title", $options);
        update_option("anc_tags", $options);
    }

    //get our options
    $options = get_option("anc_title");
    $title = $options["anc_title"];

    $options = get_option("anc_tags");
    $tags_to_parse = $options["anc_tags"];

    //print the widget control
    include("anc-insert-widget-control.php");
}

// adds anchors to content tags
function anc_add_link_text($content){
    global $tags_to_parse, $count;

    $options = get_option("anc_tags");
    $tags_to_parse = $options["anc_tags"];

    $pattern_search = array();
    $pattern_search = "/(<".$tags_to_parse.".*>)(.*)(<\/".$tags_to_parse.">)/isxmU";

    return preg_replace_callback($pattern_search, "anc_replacement", $content, -1);
}

// aux funtion to add_link_text
function anc_replacement($matches){
    global $tags_to_parse, $count;
    $count++;
    return "<a name=\"".$count."\"></a>"."<".$tags_to_parse.">".$matches[2]."</".$tags_to_parse.">";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `$pattern_search` variable with this:

```
$pattern_search = "/(<h1 .*(".$tags_to_parse.")+ .*>)+(.*)+(<\/h1>)/isxmU";
```

Now you can pass class to your function:

```
$tags_to_parse = "grve-element";
```

## Update

```
$tags_to_parse = "grve-element";
$content = '<h1 class="grve-element grve-align-left grve-title-striped" style="">Visit</h1>sf efew <h1 grve-element>rffef</h1>';
$pattern_search = "/\<h1 .(".$tags_to_parse.")?[^\>]*\>(.*?)\<\/h1\>/";
preg_match_all($pattern_search, $content, $patterns);
print_r($patterns[2]);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Visit [1] => rffef )
```

Comment: Hi Mangesh,Thank you for your advice! I entered exactly what you have suggested in the PHP document. Unfortunetly it's not working =( the URL is devtestbed.daxcentre.org if this is helpful, if it is showing results in the HTML?

Comment: I replaced the code as you instructed in the update and I am getting the output as described under Output so I must be missing something here? It's not creating anchor links from the H1 styled elements, it's only showing Array ( [0] => Visit [1] => rffef ) on every page as you can see on http://devtestbed.daxcentre.org/ =(